# How can I get the metadata from an rmarkdown document without processing it?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to loop through a set of rmarkdown documents to create a dynamic top-level table-of-contents. Is there a simple way to get the metadata from each document without actually processing the document?  I can write a small parser easily enough, but if there is such functionality already available, it would be great to use it.  The rmarkdown and knitr package docs didn't turn up anything in quick searching, but I could easily have missed something.

Comment: Open files, read lines corresponding to yaml header, feed to yaml parser?

Comment: You aren't really going to know for sure if lines that start with, say, `## text` are in a heading or in a code block (etc) w/o actually doing the markdown processing. If it's just the YAML part then you can extract those lines and use the `yaml` package. There's also https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/pandocfilters/README.html which may help generate metadata.

Comment: If you're looking for a TOC over several files, maybe you want bookdown? https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown